# SpriteKit / Swift - How to check contact of two nodes when they are already in contact

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, nodes, contacts

In my game, when the game begins, some nodes are already in contact but I don't find how to detect these contacts. I only succeed to detect contacts that happen when nodes are moving and getting in contact during the game using the function didBeginContact.

Anyone has an idea please how to detect these contacts?

Here is my didBeginContact if needed:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB

        contactsList.append([firstBody.node!,secondBody.node!])
    }
}
```

Comment: good question, I guess sprite nodes starting a game touching doesn't work with didBeginContact.  I think your only other option is didEndContact but that doesn't seem to be what you want.

Comment: Have you tested if didBeginContact is called for 2 bodies already touching? Logically, I would think that during the very first pass over the scene, if the physics engine finds 2 physics bodies overlapping, it will call didBeginContact. It will then add these bodies to a list and not call didBeginContact on the next pass if they are still touching, but call didEndContact if they are no longer touching and remove them from the list.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, no unfortunately didBeginContact is not called. I exactly did the same way as you said !

Comment: @Oscar Can you provide the code which can produce what you are saying?

Comment: @Whirlwind I just added my code

Comment: Okay, but how did you defined bit masks and set physics bodies on nodes... I meant full code which can reproduce the issue you are talking about. This code is not enough. Also, did you set physicsWorld.contactDelegate property? Anyways, I will try to reproduce by myself what you are saying and get back to you with results shortly.

Answer (score 2):

I've just tried to make two sprites overlap from the very beginning and contact is detected for me. Here is the code:

```
import SpriteKit

struct Collider {
    static let SmallSquare     : UInt32 = 1 << 0
    static let BigSquare       : UInt32 = 1 << 1
}

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        let smallSquare = SKSpriteNode(color: .orangeColor(), size: CGSize(width: 50, height:50))
        smallSquare.zPosition = 2
        smallSquare.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
        smallSquare.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: smallSquare.size)
        smallSquare.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        smallSquare.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Collider.SmallSquare
        smallSquare.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Collider.BigSquare
        smallSquare.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        addChild(smallSquare)

        let bigSquare = SKSpriteNode(color: .purpleColor(), size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
        bigSquare.zPosition = 1
        bigSquare.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
        bigSquare.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bigSquare.size)
        bigSquare.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        bigSquare.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Collider.BigSquare
        bigSquare.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Collider.SmallSquare
        bigSquare.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        addChild(bigSquare)

    }

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        print("Contact detected")
    }    
}
```

Later on, to appropriately detect contact between certain bodies, you should do something like this:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        var firstBody, secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {

            firstBody = contact.bodyA
            secondBody = contact.bodyB
        } else {

            firstBody = contact.bodyB
            secondBody = contact.bodyA
        }


        if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & Collider.SmallSquare) != 0 &&
            (secondBody.categoryBitMask & Collider.BigSquare != 0)) {

                print ("Contact detected")
        }

    }
```

But even without that, the message will be printed when game is started for the first time because contact is detected by physics world anyways.