# Physics of node not working.(Sprite kit)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a spritekit game where you need to move the player back and forth to catch objects falling down the screen. (You gain a point when the player collides with the falling object.)Recently I added restart button function. Before the restart button comes up everything works fine but when I restart the scene and the objects fall to hit the player the player falls off the screen once they make contact. This is odd because I have already set it to make the player (or person) not affected by gravity and not to be dynamic. Again before I press the button it works fine. Why are the characteristics of the person not there once I restart the scene. If you could take a look at my code and tell me why this is happening I would greatly appreciate it.

```
import SpriteKit


struct physicsCatagory {
    static let person : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
    static let Ice : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
    static let IceTwo : UInt32 = 0x1 << 3
    static let IceThree : UInt32 = 0x1 << 4
    static let Score : UInt32 = 0x1 << 5
}


class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {



    func restartScene(){
        self.removeAllChildren()
        self.removeAllActions()
        scorenumber = 0
        lifenumber = 0
        createScene()
        random()
        //spawnThirdIce()
        Died = false



    }

    func createScene(){



        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self


        lifenumber = 0
        SpeedNumber = 1

        BackGround.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
        BackGround.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 2)
        BackGround.zPosition = -5
        self.addChild(BackGround)


        Score.size = CGSize(width: 2563, height: 1)
        Score.position = CGPoint(x: 320, y: -20)
        Score.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Score.size)
        Score.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        Score.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        Score.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCatagory.Score
        Score.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        Score.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCatagory.IceThree
        Score.color = SKColor.blueColor()
        Score.zPosition = -5
        self.addChild(Score)


        person.zPosition = 1
        person.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/10)
        person.setScale(0.6)
        person.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 40, height: 50))
        person.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        person.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCatagory.person
        person.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCatagory.Ice
        person.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = physicsCatagory.Ice
        person.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        person.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false




        ScoreLable = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Zapfino")
        ScoreLable.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: 1700)
        ScoreLable.text = "\(scorenumber)"
        ScoreLable.fontColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        ScoreLable.fontSize = 150
        ScoreLable.fontName = "Zapfino "
        self.addChild(ScoreLable)


        self.addChild(person)




    }


    func random() -> CGFloat{

        return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
    }
    func random(min min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
        return random() * (max - min) + min
    }


    var gameArea: CGRect

    override init(size: CGSize) {


        let maxAspectRatio: CGFloat = 16.0/9.0
        let playableWidth = size.height / maxAspectRatio
        let margin = (size.width - playableWidth) / 2
        gameArea = CGRect(x: margin, y: 0, width: playableWidth, height: size.height)

        super.init(size: size)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    var timeOfLastSpawn: CFTimeInterval = 0.0
    var timePerSpawn: CFTimeInterval = 1.2
    var scorenumber = Int()
    var lifenumber = Int()
    var SpeedNumber : Double = 0.5
    var person = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Person1")
    let Score = SKSpriteNode()
    var ScoreLable = SKLabelNode()
    let BackGround = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "BackGround")
    var restartButton = SKSpriteNode()
    var Died = Bool()
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        createScene()



    }


    func createButton(){

        restartButton = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blueColor(), size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 100))
        restartButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.gameArea.width/2, y: self.gameArea.height/2)
        restartButton.zPosition = 6
        self.addChild(restartButton)

    }

     func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
            let firstBody = contact.bodyA
            let secondBody = contact.bodyB


        if firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.person && secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.IceThree || firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.IceThree && secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.person{

           scorenumber++

            if scorenumber == 20 {

              timePerSpawn = 1.0

            }

            if scorenumber == 40{
                timePerSpawn = 0.89

            }
            if scorenumber == 60{

                timePerSpawn = 0.6
            }
            if scorenumber == 80{

                timePerSpawn = 0.5
            }

            if scorenumber == 100{

                timePerSpawn = 0.4
            }

            if scorenumber == 120{

                timePerSpawn = 0.3
            }



            ScoreLable.text = "\(scorenumber)"
            CollisionWithPerson(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Person: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)


        }

        if firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.Score && secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.IceThree ||
            firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.IceThree && secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.Score{
                lifenumber++

                if lifenumber == 1{
                    //person.texture
                    person.texture = SKTexture (imageNamed: "Flower#2")
                }

                if lifenumber == 2{
            person.texture = SKTexture (imageNamed: "Flower #3")

        }
                if lifenumber == 3{
                    createButton()
                   // self.view?.presentScene(EndScene())
                    Died = true
                }


        }
    }



    func CollisionWithPerson (Ice: SKSpriteNode, Person: SKSpriteNode){

      Person.removeFromParent()

    }


    func spawnThirdIce(){



        var Ice = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ice")
        Ice.zPosition = 2
        Ice.setScale(1.5)
        Ice.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Ice.size)
        Ice.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCatagory.IceThree
        Ice.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCatagory.person | physicsCatagory.Score
        Ice.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        Ice.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

        let randomXStart = random(min:CGRectGetMinX(gameArea), max: CGRectGetMaxX(gameArea))
        let randomXend = random(min:CGRectGetMinX(gameArea),max: CGRectGetMaxX(gameArea))

        let startPoint = CGPoint(x: randomXStart, y: self.size.height * 1.2)
        let endpoint = CGPoint(x: randomXend, y: -self.size.height * 0.2)
        Ice.position = startPoint
        let moveEnemy = SKAction.moveTo(endpoint, duration: 2.0)
        let deleteEnemy = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        let enemySequence = SKAction.sequence([moveEnemy , deleteEnemy])
        Ice.runAction(enemySequence)

        self.addChild(Ice)



    }

        override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

            for touch in touches{
                let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

                if Died == true{
                    if restartButton.containsPoint(location){
                        restartScene()

                    }


                }

            }


    }








    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        if Died == true {



        }
        else{



        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            let previousTouch = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)
            let ammountDragged = location.x - previousTouch.x


            person.position.x += ammountDragged


            if person.position.x > CGRectGetMaxX(gameArea) - person.size.width/2{
                person.position.x = CGRectGetMaxX(gameArea) - person.size.width/2
            }

                if person.position.x <  CGRectGetMinX(gameArea) + person.size.width/2{
                    person.position.x = CGRectGetMinX(gameArea) + person.size.width/2



            }


            }

        }





    }




    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
        if (currentTime - timeOfLastSpawn > timePerSpawn) {
            spawnThirdIce()
            self.timeOfLastSpawn = currentTime
        }
    }




}
```

Comment: It is not pushed but rather removed from the parent because you don't handle contacts as it should (more precisely, you don't determine correctly which sprite is a person and which one is an ice). Also if you are not interested in collision, person's collisionBitMask should be 0. To debug this, check inside `CollisionWithPerson` method is person really a person, or it is an ice node ;) See here how to implement `didBeginContact` properly : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36887884/3402095

Comment: try removing this line in collision and see if it works for you. person.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = physicsCatagory.Ice.. the entire collision category is a bit congested sort of speak. it is a bit more efficient if you separate these collisions. anyhow you don't need to set the collision bit mask of the ice within the person. rewrite another collision set for ice and declare it there, so remove that line and see if your collision works when you restarting.